# Odd MySQL table issues after recovering from a server crash

Tags: mysql

We had a disk failure and managed to recover the `/var/lib/mysql` directory. I set up a new server and extracted `mysql/` directory back into the `/var/lib/mysql`. I noticed a table was missing, oddly. So, I thought I will just create it: `mysql> create table auth_user(id int(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);`

When I do this I get this error:
`ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'cion_crew.auth_user' already exists`

The output of `show tables` does not consist of `auth_user`, how can it say that it exists? See here:

`mysql> show tables;
+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_cion_crew        |
+----------------------------+
| accounts_userprofile       |
| auth_group                 |
| auth_group_permissions     |
| auth_permission            |
| auth_user_groups           |
| auth_user_user_permissions |
| django_admin_log           |
| django_content_type        |
| django_migrations          |
| django_session             |
| search_searchterm          |
| skills_creditoptions       |
| skills_skills              |
+----------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

I don't see it in the show tables. Naturally, I tried to do the following:

`mysql> desc cion_crew.auth_user;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'cion_crew.auth_user' doesn't exist
mysql> desc auth_user;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'cion_crew.auth_user' doesn't exist
mysql>`

Does anyone know what's going on here and what can I do? I'd like to bring back that `auth_user` table that exists/doesn't

The `/var/lib/mysql` is owned by user `mysql`

Comment: You can't typically just restore the directory unless you've done a proper backup. Usually, you need to import the data from a backup of the exported data.

Comment: Ed, we've had other failures before and this usually works out OK. I know the optimal solution is a proper db dump but unfortunately the company that had this server set up tossed it in a corner and was forgotten, until today.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Unfortunately, it sounds like you have some data corruption. It's going to be very difficult to recover from this without a backup. If it's possible, I'm afraid I don't know how to do it; when I've had similar problems, nothing worked except for rebuilding the database from backups. Good luck.

Comment: Ed - yea, that's what I am afraid of but I've seen others have some luck before, I have a glimmer of hope that someone on here might know of a solution :)